# how to hide a dropdown menu once selected in angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Hello i am new to angularjs and make a demo of dropdown menu ,I want to hide it once any of menu selected,please help me how to do this?

**html**

```
  <span class="toolbar-button--quiet navigation-bar__line-height" style="padding: 0;">
        <i class="ion-android-more-vertical" style="font-size: 26px; margin: 0; padding: 0 12px;" dropdown-menu="ddMenuOptions" dropdown-model="ddMenuSelected" dropdown-disabled="dropdownsDisabled"></i>         
    </span>
```

**js**

```
  $scope.ddMenuOptions = [
    {
      text: 'Featured',
      code: 'F'        
    }, {
      text: 'Name (A-Z)',
      code: 'A'
    },{
      text: 'Rating',
      code: 'M'
    },{
      text: ' Most Popular',
      code: 'MP'
    }
  ];

  $scope.ddMenuSelected = {


  };
```

Answer (score 0):

A fiddle would have been better. Nevertheless, you can achieve this by using a flag/variable. This variable gets updated whenever you select or dropdown is shown. Once you select an option, set the variable's value to false/true and then in the HTML tag use ng-show="yourVariable" .

```
    <span ng-show="yourVariable"></span>
```

Just make sure you update the value of this variable whenever you open the dropdown and select an option.

Comment: thanks for fast answer dear.but my div is dynamically generating,So i really dont know how to hide it once its selected