# how to apply css class condtionally in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Hello i am newbie to angularjs and have made a very simple demo of some buttons and css classes.now i am having 4 buttons i need to give my "active" css class when one of 4 buttons is selected,my code is as below,i have gone through this link but its for checkbox and i have no idea about implementing this on buttons  **[change css class dynamically](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/eTTZj/)**

**html**

```
<div class="tab-btn">
    <input type="button"   ng-class="{'active': true}" ng-disabled="button.disabled" ng-show="about"   ng-click="show = 1" value="About" />
     <input type="button" ng-show="help"    ng-click="show = 2" value="Help"/>    
    <input type="button" ng-show="Info"    ng-click="show = 3" value="Special" />        
    <input type="button" ng-show="Service" ng-click="show = 4" value="Service" />            
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.tab-btn > input.active {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-top: 3px solid #babec9;
    color: #aaaeb9;
}
```

**js**

```
 $scope.show = 1;
            $scope.show1 = function(){
//        var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#divID' ) );
//            myEl.toggleClass('red');     
                $scope.show2 = false;
                 $scope.show3 = false;
                  $scope.show4 = false;




            };
               $scope.show2 = true;
            $scope.show2 = function(){

                $scope.show1 = false;
                 $scope.show3 = false;
                  $scope.show4 = false;
            };
             $scope.show3 = true;
            $scope.show3 = function(){

                $scope.show1 = false;
                 $scope.show2 = false;
                  $scope.show4 = false;
            };
             $scope.show4 = true;
              $scope.show4 = function(){

                $scope.show1 = false;
                 $scope.show2 = false;
                  $scope.show3 = false;
            };
```

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle or plnkr.co so that it is easier to explain your problem and get it answered quickly.

Comment: Use `ng-class` with boolean expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple use `ng-class="{'active': show == 1}"` expression in ngShow:

```js
angular.module('demo', []).controller("DemoController", function($scope) {
    $scope.show = 2;
})
```

```css
.active {color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="DemoController">
    <div class="tab-btn">
        <input type="button" ng-class="{'active': show == 1}" ng-click="show = 1" value="About" />
        <input type="button" ng-class="{'active': show == 2}" ng-click="show = 2" value="Help" />
        <input type="button" ng-class="{'active': show == 3}" ng-click="show = 3" value="Special" />
        <input type="button" ng-class="{'active': show == 4}" ng-click="show = 4" value="Service" />
        <div style="clear: both"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33182968/how-to-hide-a-dropdown-menu-once-selected-in-angularjs/33183041?noredirect=1#comment54172953_33183041) this is my another question which is having same issue

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="tab-btn" ng-init = "show = 1" ng-controller= "SampleController">
 <input type="button" ng-disabled="show == 1" ng-class="{'active': show == 1}"  ng-click="show = 1" value="About" />
 <input type="button" ng-disabled="show == 2" ng-class="{'active': show == 2}" ng-click="show = 2" value="Help"/>    
<input type="button" ng-disabled="show == 3" ng-class="{'active': show == 3}" ng-click="show = 3" value="Special" />        
<input type="button" ng-disabled="show == 4" ng-class="{'active': show == 4}" ng-click="show = 4" value="Service" />                   
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

Comment: hi sudeep i appriciate your help dear.but i am stuck at one more point can you help me in that? please it took my whole day..(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33182968/how-to-hide-a-dropdown-menu-once-selected-in-angularjs/33183041?noredirect=1#comment54172953_33183041)